# How do you authenticate a user in a user pool via Cognito when error messages say userName and password don't match even though they do?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

So I am messing around with Cognito and their Beta User Pools feature in Javascript. I am successfully creating users thanks to the documentation found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html

When I try and authenticate the users though I get a strange error message saying:

NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password.

I don't understand why this is the case as I am literally copying and pasting the values for userName and password that I used to create the user, which is working fine.

Below is my code to authenticate the user:

```
//----- Setup
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'myIdentityPoolId'
    });

    AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';

    AWSCognito.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'myIdentityPoolId'
    });

    var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'myUserPoolId',
        ClientId : 'myClientId'
    };

//-----Authenticate a user
    alert('Authenticate a user with application');
    var authenticationData = {
        Username : 'markie17061993',
        Password : 'MeowWoof123456789!',
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'myUserPoolId',
        ClientId : 'myClientId'
    };
    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
        Username : 'markie17061993',
        Pool : userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
    alert('hiss');
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        },

    });
```

Do you see anything wrong here? I thought perhaps my UserName parameter in these two places is meant to be a different value or something:

```
var authenticationData = {
        Username : 'markie17061993',
        Password : 'MeowWoof123456789!',
    };

var userData = {
        Username : 'markie17061993',
        Pool : userPool
    };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't show if you are confirming the newly signed up user not. If you are not, that would explain the `NotAuthorizedException`. [This example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html#using-amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-javascript-example-confirming-user) specifically is what you want to follow.

If you do not want to confirm the users being signed up from you app, you should use a [PreSignUp trigger](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-registration-example) to `autoConfirm` your users.

Comment: When I set up the user pool I didn't choose to have phone or email verification, so I don't think this is it, or am I missing something? That's what this is referring to right?

Comment: Even if you did not, Cognito user pools by default creates users in an unconfirmed/unverified state. If you do not want that you need that PreSignUp trigger which auto confirms all users.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

Comment: Do you know why cognito does this?

Comment: Thanks, ^ the example helped me!