# AWS cognito signin issue with Xamarin forms, NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password

Tags: xamarin, amazon-cognito

I´m trying to setup cognito user authentication by using user pools and xamarin for my mobile app (cross platform)

I have setup user pool with default policy (8 char pass,special char, etc) and created an app client with no client secret.

So, when I execute the app I´m able to sing up a new user, then I receive a confirmation code via email, and also I´m able to confirm user by sending the code received.

Everything seems to be working just fine, the issue is when I try to log into the app I always receive the error "NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password." and I have tried everything, hardcode the user/pass, recreate the user pool, change policies, and I cannot find any clue on why it´s failing.

Here is my code for the authentication piece:

**Login button:**

```
private async void Login(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CognitoHelper cognitoHelper = new CognitoHelper();
                cognitoUser = await cognitoHelper.ValidateUser(UsuarioEntry.Text, PasswordEntry.Text);
                Console.WriteLine(cognitoUser.Username);

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp);
                await DisplayAlert("Error","Unable to validate the username and password","Ok");
            }
        }
```

**CognitoHelper class (validate user method)**

```
public async Task<CognitoUser> ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider =
                new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), REGION);

        CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(this.POOL_ID, this.CLIENTAPP_ID, provider);

        CognitoUser cognitoUSer = new CognitoUser(username, this.CLIENTAPP_ID, userPool, provider);
        AuthFlowResponse context = await cognitoUSer.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
        {
            Password = password
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return cognitoUSer;
    }
```

Comment: Is this help?[how-do-you-authenticate-a-user-in-a-user-pool-via-cognito-when-error-messages-sa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025000/how-do-you-authenticate-a-user-in-a-user-pool-via-cognito-when-error-messages-sa)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it does not help, in my case I´m able to confirm the users and in cognito console I can see them as confirmed and I keep getting that same error